# Add / subtract characters as Int in Swift

Tags: swift, string, character

I need to implement an algorithm to check if an input is valid by calculating a modulo of a String.

The code in Kotlin:

```
private val facteurs = arrayOf(7, 3, 1)

private fun modulo(s: String): Int {
    var result = 0
    var i = -1
    var idx = 0
    for (c in s.toUpperCase()) {
        val value:Int
        if (c == '<') {
            value = 0
        } else if (c in "0123456789") {
            value = c - '0'
        } else if (c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") {
            value = c.toInt() - 55
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected character: $c at position $idx")
        }
        i += 1
        result += value * facteurs[i % 3]
        idx += 1
    }
    return result % 10
}
```

This implies doing math operations on the characters.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Swift 3 and 4?

I tried some cumbersome constructs like this :

```
value = Int(c.unicodeScalars) - Int("0".first!.unicodeScalars)
```

But it does not even compile.
I'm currently using Swift 4 with XCode9, but Swift3 answer is welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate the `unicodeScalars` view of a string together
with the running index, use switch/case pattern matching,
and access the numeric `.value` of the unicode scalar:

```
func modulo(_ s: String) -> Int? {
    let facteurs = [7, 3, 1]
    var result = 0
    for (idx, uc) in s.uppercased().unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
        let value: UInt32
        switch uc {
        case "<":
            value = 0
        case "0"..."9":
            value = uc.value - UnicodeScalar("0").value
        case "A"..."Z":
            value = uc.value - UnicodeScalar("A").value + 10
        default:
            return nil
        }
        result += Int(value) * facteurs[idx % facteurs.count]
    }
    return result % 10
}
```

This compiles with both Swift 3 and 4. Of course you could also
`throw` an error instead of returning `nil` for invalid input.

Note that `"<"`, `"0"`, `"9"` etc.
in the switch statement are inferred from the context as `UnicodeScalar`,
not as `String` or `Character`, therefore `"0"..."9"` (in this context)
is a `ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>` and `uc` can be matched against
that range.

Comment: In swift 4 you can just iterate over the string.

Comment: @DonovanKing: Yes, but I want the `unicodeScalars`, not the  `characters`. That allows to match against a range, and to do computations on the value.

Comment: Ah I see...ya this is a better solution. Have an up vote +1

Comment: Much more elegant than what I wrote. Thank you. +1.

Comment: Is there is a good way to get rid of that hardcoded `55`? I assume that's to convert `"A"` to 10, `"Z"` to 36, etc. I guess `value = uc.value - UnicodeScalar("A").value + 10`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Indeed, that is a plausible assumption, and you are guessing correctly – code updated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this works for me:

```
"A".utf16.first! + 2 //comes out to 67
```

Careful with the forced unwrap "!"

If you need the scalars value you can do

```
"A".unicodeScalars.first!.value + 2
```

More reading can be done on this [here in the SPL](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285).

For the `c` Character type value you could do this:

```
String(c).unicodeScalars.first!.value + 2
```

Here is an attempt to mod the function:

```
func modulo(s: String) -> Int? {
var result = 0
var factors = [7,3,1]
for (i, c) in s.uppercased().characters.enumerated() {
    let char = String(c)
    var val: Int
    if char == "<" {
        val = 0
    } else if "0123456789".contains(char) {
        val = Int(char.unicodeScalars.first!.value - "0".unicodeScalars.first!.value)
    } else if "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".contains(char) {
        val = Int(char.unicodeScalars.first!.value - 55)
    } else {
        return nil
    }

       result += val * factors[(i) % 3]
    }

    return result % 10
}
```

This is in swift 3...in 4 I believe you can just iterate over the string without converting to Chars

Comment: The type of `c` is Character, Xcode says that  'utf16' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level.

Comment: @Xvolks ah ok, lemme take a look.

Comment: And also Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character.UnicodeScalarView.Element' (aka 'Unicode.Scalar') and 'Int'

Comment: @Xvolks Did you get the value out before using the '-' ?

Comment: `let value = Int(c.unicodeScalars.first!.value) - 55` works but it seems a way overkill to do such simple thing...

Comment: You shouldn't have to init a new Int there...lemme fix the function itself.